# mapping a collection via IUserType

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, usertype, iusertype

I need to load a class (Adjustment) with some logic, so I implemented the IUserType in Nhibernate. When it's a single reference, it works fine:

```
    Map(p => p.DefaultAdjustment)
        .CustomType(typeof(AdjustmentCustomMap));
```

Its SqlType is string.
However, I have a collection from Adjustment as well, I dont know how can I map it !

```
        HasMany(p => p.Adjustments)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Inverse())
            ;
```

**how can I get my implementation of IUserType to load the collection?**
I'm using NH 3.3
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.Element()` with your `HasMany` mapping. Since you are not mapping a collection of entities, but a collection of *simple* objects, you need to use the same mapping as you would have if mapping a collection of `string`, `int`, `Guid`...

```
HasMany(p => p.Adjustments)
    .Element("Adjustment", e => e.Type<AdjustmentCustomMap>())
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
    .Inverse())
    ;
```

The first parameter of `Element` method is a column name.

Comment: the problem is when I add something to the list, NHibernate doesn't persist it. it can retrieve the data, but not save it

Comment: What if you remove `.Inverse()` from your mapping? http://colinramsay.co.uk/diary/2008/03/15/nhibernates-inverse-attribute/ If that doesn't help, try debugging your custom type. See if the Set method is being called.